# sqlsrv_connect works fine but laravel fails with : TCP Provider: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: php, laravel, sqlsrv

unfortuantely i have to make laravel talk to sql server .. i normally use mysql.. and have developed a swift hatred for sql server..

i'm running xampp on localhost for development. I can connect and query to local sql server fine with navicat and with sql server management studio.

sqlsrv_connect works fine in php, and i can run queries manually with no problem.
mssql_connect works fine in php, and i can run queries manually with no problem.

but laravel fails.

in env:

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlsrv
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=handheld2
DB_USERNAME=handheld
DB_PASSWORD=thepasswordhere
DB_PORT=1433
```

and in laravel database config:

```
'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL', 'localhost'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'handheld2'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', ''),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
]
```

i'm not clear what 'url' is for? how is this different to db_host ?

i receive

Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

both php_sqlsrv_72_ts_x64.dll and php_pdo_sqlsrc_72_x64.dll are enabled in php

am i missing something simple and obvious?

edit: note that this code works

```
$connectionInfo = array(
    "Database"=>"handheld2",
    "UID" => "handheld",
    "PWD" => "thepasswordhere",
);
$conn = sqlsrv_connect("localhost", $connectionInfo);
if ($conn === false) {
    echo "Could not connect.\n";
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, 'SELECT top 1 * from users where users.id = 1');
if($stmt === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

and prints out record from db.. so why does it work here but not though laravel ???

Comment: Have you tried `php artisan config:clear`?

Comment: i just did.. cache cleared successfully, but no change

Comment: I don't have SQL Server or Windows, but couldn't be a port issue in your firewall? try making it wide open, also I think that the host should start with `Server\`

Answer (score 1):

debugging in laravels files in vendor.. turns out it was trying to connect to 'andheld2' instead of 'handheld2'

changing

'url' => env('DATABASE_URL', 'handheld2'),

to

'url' => env('DATABASE_URL', '/handheld2'),

in the database config makes it work.. it apparently ignores the first character.. for some reason? whatever.

Answer (score 1):

It’s an old question but we had the same problem with the sqlsrv php driver. This was caused by the dynamic ports of the sql server - switching to specific port solved the problem for us.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-a-server-to-listen-on-a-specific-tcp-port

Comment: Hey there! You just saved about one day of work for us  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

For me the solution was to remove the port in the .env file
It has something to do with dynamic ports.

same as mentioned in other comments.

My code in .env

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlsrv
DB_HOST=USERNAMESERVE\SQLEXPRESS
DB_PORT=
DB_DATABASE=DB_NAME
DB_USERNAME=sa
DB_PASSWORD=sa
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else finds themselves here maybe this will help.

After hours of banging my head against the wall, the fix for me in the end was extremely simple. I was working with a fresh install of everything (including Sql Server) and I had to open Sql Server Configuration Manager ([which itself is a pain in the butt in Windows 10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-configuration-manager?view=sql-server-ver15)...I ended up having to just search in the windows folder for SQLServerManager because I didn't know the exact version number, which was 15).

Then > SQL Server Network Configuation > Protocols for MSSQLSERVER > TCP/IP was disabled. Enabled this, restart SQLSERVER in Windows Services and viola, laravel works.